# Identify Japanese Font Name?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

Can anybody help me identify the Japanese font in this picture? I have tried seveal font identification services, but they don't seem to recognize Japanese symbols.

[image]

Comment: Font identification services might not work well with Japanese fonts, but it could also be because your image is low res, distorted and faint.

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Photoshop's "Match Font" feature, it came up with the following list of fonts:

1. Hiragino Mincho Pro W3
2. Hiragino Mincho ProN W3
3. Hiragino Mincho Pro W6
4. Hiragino Mincho ProN W6
5. Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro W3
6. Hiragino Sans W3
7. Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN W3
8. Hiragino Sans W2
9. Hiragino Sans W4
10. Hiragino Sans W5
    (Keep in mind that these are Adobe Fonts.)

Here is a screenshot of the fonts with glyphs:

[image]

Comment: Just shows how unreliable that is, because apart from the Mincho W3 weights, it’s very obviously none of those. It may be Mincho W3, but it’s a bit hard to tell just by comparing the screenshots since the only characters they have in common are もじ.